# How to use WKExtendedRuntimeSession and WCSession together

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I need watchOS program to run in **background** and **communicated** with iOS.

Can I use `WKExtendedRuntimeSession` and `WCSession` together?

Or is there another way to solve the problem?

I didn't find a solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @PrateekVarshney. I didn’t find the solution so I don’t have code :(